# how can I make a graph with multiple choices in access?

Tags: ms-access, graph

A couple days ago I made with access a table with a field of multiples options(32 options), using the lookup wizards and I add the option allow multiple values, but when I want to make a graph it only take me the first value.

this is the field how the user make the selection:

[image]

This is the graph with seven users and they choose multiple answers(as you see it only take me the first option)

[image]

How can I separate all the answers in this field in particular so I can make a graph with each value.

Answer (score 0):

I found the soluction apperently when I do a query I need to add to the multiple field the sentence ".Value",

[image]

In that way I can split all the info in differents fields.